# WebBrowser control that can handle HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, https, webbrowser-control

I am searching for a substitute of the WebBrowser control in .NET which can handle HTTPS. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome) is similar here on Stack Overflow, but none of these controls offer HTTPS.

btw, just to mention, I tried all these

[GeckoFx](http://www.geckofx.org/) - development stopped
[Se7en](http://se7en-soft.com/moznet/features.aspx) - this is actually continued GeckoFx
[Webkitdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) - no one replying on forum

but none of them support HTTPS, so I'm kind of stuck here :/.

Also, to mention, WebBrowser control that comes with .NET framework works just fine with HTTPS, but the reason I can't use it is because my app uses **a lot** of javascript that IE refuses to render, and for example Firefox (gecko engine) or Chrome (webkit) work just fine.

So, please if someone knows a good control that can do this (can be Webkit or Gecko wrapper, it doesn't mind, as long as it's not an IE wrapper).

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik Mozilla team recently announced that they won't be supporting embedding via Gecko engine from now. So your only option is webkit or some custom webbrowser component + JS engine.

Comment: If the web application is **your application**, wouldn't making it compatible with IE be... you know... important and all?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: actually no. This is not a web application per se. This is a web application but hosted through a windows form. I mean, I'm not the dev of the web app, I just had to make sure it will work in a web browser control inside the form. Why like that? Ah, I stopped worrying about my superiors demands a while ago, and just do the job...

Comment: I updated my answer with a new framework that I wasn't aware of previously. Chromium Embedded Framework. Have not tried it yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long googling I finally ended up using the [same as I was using before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579631/webkitdotnet-unable-to-load-https-site). So Webkit from http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet and I ended up purchasing a SSL certificate for my domain and now all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since I, apparently, cannot write a comment I'll just drop my 2 cents here..
Beginning with the next release (R14), [MozNET](http://se7en-soft.com/moznet/) (called 'Se7en' in the OP's post), will have support for HTTPS/SSL and the ability to accept/deny certificates.

EDIT: The R15 release will have the SSL handling for sure. I had to hold off on it because of a weird bug.. But, it's coming soon!

Answer (score 1):

Your options here seem a bit limited. With IE8 and IE9 the JavaScript is not so bad, but if there is no possibility for your users to upgrade, I would suggest looking at a few things:

- [Mono.WebBrowser](http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser)
- [Mozilla XulRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) - This is not directly a .NET control, but could be useful anyway.

**Update:**

I recently ran into this, might be interesting:

- [.Net binding for the Chromium Embedded Framework](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp)